# Create image dataset for multiple classes

Tags: python, keras

I am a new user in python,and need some help for my image dataset code, I want to make dataset in the form of (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test). I already have image in my directory. I have multiple classes in my dataset directory with train and test folder.

I want to read the entire images from directory. I already have tried with some code but it throws an error.

```
row = 256
column = 256
channel = 3
class = 30 random

train = 'directory'
test = 'directory'
train_images = [train+i for i in os.listdir(train)]
test_images =  [test+i for i in os.listdir(test)]

def read_image(filepath):
    img = cv2.imread(filepath,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)#i have RGB images
    return
def prepare_data(images):
    x = len(images)
    y = np.zeros((x,row,column,channel),dtype=np.uint8)
    z = np.zeros((class,x))
    for i,image_file in enumerate(images)
    a[i,:] = read image(image_file)   #here how i get all images from different classes directories
     if 'class1' in image_file.lower():
         z[0,i] = class name1
     elif 'class2' in image_file.lower():
         z[1,i] = class name2
     elif 'class3' in image_file.lower():
         z[2,i]  = class name3
       ...
       ....
       ....
     return y,z
```

Here I have face problem it can not access entire image from different classes. Can anyone help me please how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the file names, load the file using the function you wrote - `read_image()` and append it to a list. Also based on the condition on names, you can append labels too.

See below code for implementation of `perpare_data()` function.

```
def prepare_data(images):

    x, y = [], []

    for image_file in images:
        img = read_image(image_file)
        x.append(img)

        if 'class1' in image_file.lower():
            y.append(class_name_1)
        elif 'class2' in image_file.lower():
            y.append(class_name_2)
        elif 'class3' in image_file.lower():
            y.append(class_name_3)

    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)

    return x, y
```

You can use it as shown below to get `x` and `y` arrays as needed.

```
train_x, train_y = prepare_data(train_images)
test_x, test_y = prepare_data(test_images)
```

Also, you have to change the path definition like this,

```
train = 'directory//'
test = 'directory//'
```

In the code you provided for reading image you are not returning the image after that is read, update that code like shown below,

```
def read_image(filepath):
    img = cv2.imread(filepath,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)#i have RGB images
    return img
```

Comment: Dear thanks for your reply but when i run this code at the end i got error 
 def prepare_data(images):
      x , y = [], []
     for i, image_file in images:
          img = read_image(image_file)
          x.append(img)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) now i want to check my data are already made or not i use print command to see the arrays but i got this error

Comment: I have updated the answer, If the problem still exist update your question to show full error trace

Comment: Dear thanks for your reply i tried but it is not work give error about **values to unpack error** i dont understand i also change my code as you said my directories also `train= "D:/simulation/dataset/train"` `test="D:/simulation/dataset/test"` i have done that but i got remain same error.if you share me your email id i will send you my code if you......thanks